# google charts - only 1 set of data shown

Tags: google-visualization

i have a chart with the code:

```
    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Intensidade');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Afundamento %');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Elevação %');
        var fool =[<?php echo $jsRows_intensidade_eleva; ?>];
        data.addRows(fool);
        var foo = [<?php echo $jsRows_intensidade;?>];
        data.addRows(foo);




    var options = {
        title: '',
        hAxis: {title: 'Intensidade (p.u.)', minValue: 0, maxValue: 2},
        vAxis: {title: 'Prob. de ocorrência em %', minValue: 0, maxValue: 100}

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_intensidade_NRS-048'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});
```

In which the arrays are written as:

```
//$jsRows[] = "['Duração','Afundamento']";
for($i=0;$i<count($datay_afunda_intensidade);$i++){
$jsRows_intensidade[] = "[{$datax_afunda_intensidade[$i]},{$datay_afunda_intensidade[$i]},null]";
}

//$jsRows_eleva[] ="['Duração','Elevação']";
for($i=0;$i<count($datay_eleva_intensidade);$i++){
$jsRows_intensidade_eleva[] = "[{$datax_eleva_intensidade[$i]},null,{$datay_eleva_intensidade[$i]}]";
}


$jsRows_intensidade = implode(",",$jsRows_intensidade);
$jsRows_intensidade_eleva = implode(",",$jsRows_intensidade_eleva);
```

but it's showing just the set of rows presented on the column 'Afundamento %', it ignores the second one. Does anyone see an error in this code ? It was working a little time ago. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

jsRows_intensidade = [0.53,12.5,null],[0.59,25,null],[0.54,12.5,null],[0.55,12.5,null],[1,12.5,null],[0.36,12.5,null],[0.01,12.5,null]

js_Rows_intensidade_eleva = [1.5,null,50],[1,null,50]

Comment: Could you post some examples of what is being output by `echo $jsRows_intensidade_eleva;` and `echo $jsRows_intensidade;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a case where the chart is simply too narrow to display your data.  The API measures the smallest distance between any two data points and assigns that as the maximum bar group width in data units (in your case, 0.01).  The length of the domain axis (x-axis for ColumnCharts) is divided by this value to get the number of total bar groups that can be drawn, and the pixel-width of an individual bar group is determined by dividing the width of the chart area (the part where the bars are drawn) by the maximum number of bar groups.  Within each bar group, the API reserves space for padding between bar groups (about 33% by default), and then reserves space for bars starting with the first series of data (bars get space reserved even if they have no data at a given axis value).  If the bar group runs out of space, then any remaining bars have a width of 0, which is what is happening with your second series.

There are a few of ways you can address this problem:

1. You can increase the width of your chart, or use the `chartArea.width` option to increase the width of the chart area.
2. If your chart is nearly wide enough, you can give the bar groups a bit of extra space to draw bars by increasing the percentage of the group width allocated for bars by setting the `bar.groupWidth` option to a larger value than its default (~67%, max 100%) (eg: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/umVHX/).
3. You can use a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) to allow the user to pan and zoom the chart (eg: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/umVHX/1/).

Comment: That's it! :) Thanks once more for the very good answer and examples.  I got option 2.